# DosBox boot MBR, wrong value in dl for int 13h

Tags: assembly, dosbox, mbr

I have a custom MBR that I compile with NASM to a binary and I can boot it just fine in qemu and bochs.

I am trying to boot this MBR in DosBox using `boot mbr.bin`. This works fine as long as the MBR is tiny and does not call `int 13h` to read sectors from the disk.

If I try to read the next sector, it fails, resulting in a disk read error of some sort. I imagine this has to do with the value of `dl` not being set to the "boot drive". I've tried manually setting `dl` to 0 and to 80h, but neither work.

Does anyone know what the value of `dl` should be to make `int 13h` work in DosBox using the `boot` command? Or if there is perhaps some other way to obtain that value dynamically?

Edit; here is the initial code:

```
CPU 386
BITS 16
org 7C00h

; Calculate the full size of the code from start of segment $$ to the end label at the bottom (end - $$)
%define SECTORS_TO_LOAD ((end - $$) / 512) + ((end - $$) % 512 > 0) - 1

main:
    jmp 0x0000:setcs
    ; Some error messages
    disk_err db "Error reading disk", 0
    sector_err db "Error reading sector", 0

setcs:
    ; Base setup

    cld

    xor ax, ax      ; Set ES=DS=0 - this can be changed later for rep operations
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    ; Clear the screen
    mov ah, 0x07    ; Function 0x07: scroll window
    mov al, 0x00    ; Clear entire window
    mov bh, 0x07    ; White on black
    mov cx, 0x00    ; Specifies top left of screen as (0,0)
    mov dh, 0x18    ; 18h = 24 rows of chars
    mov dl, 0x4f    ; 4fh = 79 cols of chars
    int 0x10    ; Video interrupt


    ; Move cursor to position 0,0
    mov ah, 0x02    ; Function 0x02: set cursor position
    mov dh, 0x00    ; Row 0
    mov dl, 0x00    ; Col 0
    mov bh, 0x00    ; Page 0
    int 0x10    ; Video interrupt


    ; Load the calculated numbers of sector from the disk
    ; For this function call, dl should be set to the disk number to read from. The BIOS sets dl to
    ; the disk number of the MBR and dl was not changed, so we don't have to set it.

    ;mov dl, 0x80

    mov ax, SECTORS_TO_LOAD ; Number of sectors to read
    mov bx, next_sector ; The memory address to read to
    xor ch, ch      ; Cylinder 0
    mov cl, 0x02        ; Start at sector 2 (sector 1 is the first part of the MBR)
    xor dh, dh      ; Head 0
    mov ah, 0x02        ; Read mode

    int 0x13        ; Read interrupt
    jc .disk_error      ; Check carry bit for error

    cmp al, SECTORS_TO_LOAD ; The interrupt sets 'al' to the number of sectors actually read
    jne .sectors_error

    ; After a succesful load, the layout in memory will be the same as the layout in our ASM files,
    ; so we can jump to a defined label without worrying about offsets and exact addresses.
    jmp after_load

.disk_error:
    push disk_err   ; Print a disk error message
    call print
    cli     ; Halt all interrupts and operations
    hlt

.sectors_error:
    push sector_err ; Same as above, different message
    call print
    cli
    hlt


; The print function prints a string onto the screen in text mode
print:
    push bp     ; Basic stack setup
    mov bp, sp
    pusha       ; Push everything - this function doesn't
            ; return anything

    mov si, [bp+4]  ; Grab the pointer to the data
    mov bh, 0   ; Page 0
    mov bl, 0   ; Foreground color, irrelevant - in text mode
    mov ah, 0x0E    ; Function 0x0E: print character in TTY
.char:
    mov al, [si]    ; Get current char from pointer position
    inc si      ; Keep incrementing si until a null char
    or al, 0
    je .return
    int 0x10    ; Video interrupt
    jmp .char
.return:
    popa        ; Restore registers
    mov sp, bp  ; Restore stack
    pop bp
    ret 2       ; Remove param from stack on return

times 510-($-$$) db 0

; MBR signature
db 55h, 0AAh

next_sector:
```

After that, under next_sector, it has some incbins and some other code, including the label `after_load`.

The error I get is the first one; "Error reading disk", which displays fine. So it seems that es, ds, etc. are set up right.

Note the commented out `mov dl, 0x80` - that was one of my attempts to get this working.

Comment: dosbox seems to load `dl` with zero and set drive to `A` by default. Apparently you can specify a drive with `-l` but that won't reflect in `dl`.

Comment: @Jester yeah I already found the `-l` option, but that indeed does nothing it seems.

Comment: What values do your other registers have. Perhaps the error is unrelated to the drive?

Comment: @Sebastian I've amended the question with some more code details, because posting that as a comment means I have no formatting.

Comment: Probably not related to your question but `((end - $$) / 512) + ((end - $$) % 512 > 0) - 1` doesn't seem right. The first part correctly gets the amount of 512-byte pages. Then `% 512` is nonzero if a partial page is present. Then `> 0` returns 1 if any is present, 0 if none. Then you subtract `- 1` which is wrong. And an easier way, in my opinion, to convert nonzero values to 1 and zero values to 0 is double `!`. So `((end - $$) / 512) + !! ((end - $$) % 512)`

Comment: @ecm thanks for the tip. This does work out though, since the number of sectors I want to load is the total number of sectors - 1 (which is already loaded by the BIOS). I have not run into any problems using this method in Qemu or Bochs. Everything is loaded fine. Your method looks much cleaner, though, I'll play around with it :)

Comment: You can also achieve the same effect by "rounding up" the integer division. That looks like `(end - $$ + 511) / 512`

Comment: Oh I missed that. Yes, your `end - $$` includes the first sector. So the minus one is actually justified. Sorry for the wrong nitpicking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Getting error "BIOS:Disk 0 is not active" in asm program](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?p=504583#p504583)

DOSBox uses the image size to determine the disk geometry.

Pad the bin file to 1440*1024 bytes.